# git using system rather than global config

Tags: windows, git, ssl, ssl-certificate, huggingface-transformers

git is managed by my company and I cannot modify the system config.

I have set my global SSL certificate path using `git config --global http.sslCAInfo "C:\Users\265840645\Desktop\cert\rbc-ca-bundle.cer"`

However, when I try git clone, git is still using the system config.

`fatal: unable to access 'https://huggingface.co/decapoda-research/llama-7b-hf/': error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt CApath: none`

How can I get git to use the global config?

Comment: Maybe just disable ssl verify? `git config http.sslVerify false`, git clone the transformer library, then `git config --global http.sslCAInfo `?

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable `GIT_SSL_CAINFO` to your desired CA bundle file path, you could use a command like that `set GIT_SSL_CAINFO="C:\Users\265840645\Desktop\cert\rbc-ca-bundle.cer"` then `git clone` should work.

or $env:GIT_SSL_CAINFO="C:\Users\265840645\Desktop\cert\rbc-ca-bundle.cer"
if you use PowerShell

It will only work for your current session though, to make it permanent you gonna have to add the `GIT_SSL_CAINFO` environment variable to your user or system environment variables through the Windows Control Panel.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both in the command line and in Powershell, and I am still receiving the same error. git config --global --list does show the correct path for the certificate.

Comment: Try to add it via the Windows Control Panel, and with this solution it will be permanent.

Comment: It's locked by the company.

Comment: See this problem with your system administrator